# Unable to Plot NSdate along X-axis of CorePlot

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdate, core-plot

Am new to coreplot and I want to display NSdate (year or moth or day) along the x-axis of a bargraph which is drawn using coreplot.I have gone through some samples to plot NSDate along x-axis.but am unable to plot..

Please can any one provide me the code for plotting NSDate along x-axis...
Thanks

I tried the below code from stackoverflow but am unable to display the labels on x-axis

```
// If you make sure your dates are calculated at noon, you shouldn't have to 
// worry about daylight savings. If you use midnight, you will have to adjust
// for daylight savings time.
NSDate *refDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:31556926 * 10];
NSTimeInterval oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;

// Invert graph view to compensate for iOS coordinates
//CGAffineTransform verticalFlip = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1);
// self.view.transform = verticalFlip;

 // allocate the graph within the current view bounds
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];

// assign theme to graph
CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
[graph applyTheme:theme];

// Setting the graph as our hosting layer
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

[self.view addSubview:hostingView];

hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

graph.paddingLeft = 20.0;
graph.paddingTop = 20.0;
graph.paddingRight = 20.0;
graph.paddingBottom = 150.0;

// setup a plot space for the plot to live in
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
NSTimeInterval xLow = 0.0f;
// sets the range of x values
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xLow)
                                               length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay*5.0f)];
// sets the range of y values
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) 
                                               length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(5)];

// plotting style is set to line plots
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;

// X-axis parameters setting
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (id)graph.axisSet;
axisSet.xAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
axisSet.xAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"1"); //added for date, adjust x line
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.xAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
axisSet.xAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;

// added for date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter] autorelease];
timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
axisSet.xAxis.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;

// Y-axis parameters setting    
axisSet.yAxis.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.5");
axisSet.yAxis.minorTicksPerInterval = 2;
axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay); // added for date, adjusts y line
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
axisSet.yAxis.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.majorTickLength = 7.0f;
axisSet.yAxis.labelOffset = 3.0f;


// This actually performs the plotting
CPTScatterPlot *xSquaredPlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];

CPTMutableLineStyle *dataLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
//xSquaredPlot.identifier = @"X Squared Plot";
xSquaredPlot.identifier = @"Date Plot";

dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
xSquaredPlot.dataLineStyle = dataLineStyle;
xSquaredPlot.dataSource = self;

CPTPlotSymbol *greenCirclePlotSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
greenCirclePlotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor]];
greenCirclePlotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
xSquaredPlot.plotSymbol = greenCirclePlotSymbol;  

// add plot to graph
[graph addPlot:xSquaredPlot];

// Add some data
NSMutableArray *newData = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger i;
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    NSTimeInterval x = oneDay*i;
    id y = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1.2*rand()/(float)RAND_MAX + 1.2];
    [newData addObject:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:x], [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldX], 
      y, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldY], 
      nil]];
    NSLog(@"%@",newData);
}
plotData = [newData retain];

}

#pragma mark - Plot Data Source Methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
return plotData.count;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:     (NSUInteger)index
 {
NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fieldEnum]];
return num;
}
```

Comment: If you've looked at the DatePlot and Plot Gallery examples included with Core Plot and are still having trouble, edit your question to explain what you've tried so far (with code).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking to do something like this... (I apologize for the size of the image, I am not familiar with how to size the image for SO)

[image: Key Indicators]

You will need to define custom labels for your X Axis.

Consider the following code snippet (taken from the code that generates the image above):

```
/* --Define some custom labels for the data elements-- */
// Note that x is defined as: CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet*)self.graph.axisSet;
//                                      CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone; // This allows us to create custom axis labels for x axis
NSMutableArray *ticks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
for(unsigned int counter = 0; counter < [_axisLabelStrings count];counter++) {
    // Here the instance variable _axisLabelStrings is a list of custom labels
    [ticks addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:counter]];
}
NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;
NSMutableArray* customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[_axisLabelStrings count]];
@try {
    for (NSNumber *tickLocation in ticks) {
        CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [_axisLabelStrings objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
        newLabel.offset = 3.0f;//x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength could be useful here.
        newLabel.rotation = M_PI/3.5f;
        [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
        [newLabel release];
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"An exception occurred while creating date labels for x-axis");
}
@finally {
    x.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];  
}
x.majorTickLocations = [NSSet setWithArray:ticks];
```

Note that the _axisLabelStrings will need to be processed and sorted how you want it. You will need to take NSDates, sort them, and generate NSStrings for your labels.

But that, in a nutshell, is how you create custom labels.

Comment: Can you please provide the sample code for this. I am also struck in this same issue. THANKS